# Dynamic texbox modification with ajax/php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have two tables. company_details and company_specials. Each company_details can have multiple specials. I display the company details at http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/admin.php

The first row and fourth row that has the 0 in the active column is from company_details and the rows below are from company_specials.

Currently the code allows for dynamic modification of the company_details rows as denoted by the compid in that table. However i would like to have the rows below it to be dynamically modified as well but it's using the same compid and i'm not sure how to separate them in the code.

Code below is the code being generated for the company_specials. I need a way to uniquely identify each row and be able to modify it.
http://pastebin.com/RAe9iwAP

Could somebody provide some guidance please? I'm thinking that i would probably need to uniquely identify each of the specials within the company_specials or set some sort of pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Q.I need a way to uniquely identify each row
A. you already are doing so;

```
<tr id="<?php echo $compid; ?>"
```

Q. and be able to modify it.
A. add a input button before the end of each row, that `onclick="edit(<?php echo $compid; ?>)"` and launches the editing cycle based on the $compid for that row.

Then using Javascript you can extract the contents of all the `<td></td>` within the row by the $compid in the tr like this;

```
    var originalString = "<tr>" + document.getElementById(compid).innerHTML + "</tr>";
var targetArray = [];
$(originalString) /*.find("tr")*/ .each(function(index, tr) {
  targetArray = $("td", tr).map(function(index, td) {return $(td).text();});
});
```

all of the `<td>` contents will be in targetArray variable accessible to be put into a form for editing like so;

```
document.getElementById("forminputid").value = targetArray[1];
```